# Extract rows from two data.frames that are similar in a column?

Tags: r

For the following two `data.frame`s

```
Set1 <- data.frame(Object=c("one","two","three","four"),
                   Age=c(1,1,1,1),
                   Value=c(1,2,4,8))
Set2 <- data.frame(Object=c("one","two","three","five"),
                   Age=c(2,2,2,2),
                   Value=c(4,8,2,7))
```

I want to get the entries that are repeated (according to column "Object") in both `Set1` and `Set2`, i.e.

```
  Object Age Value
1    one   1     1
2    two   1     2
3  three   1     4
4    one   2     4
5    two   2     8
6  three   2     2
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: (1) Please fix typos in your example data code, (2) Your description is extremely ambiguous; presumably you mean rows with values of `Object` that appear in both data frames...?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I have fixed the code and expressed what column the test should be applied to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> x = intersect(Set1$Object, Set2$Object)
> rbind(Set1[Set1$Object %in% x,], Set2[Set2$Object %in% x,])
  Object Age Value
1    one   1     1
2    two   1     2
3  three   1     4
4    one   2     4
5    two   2     8
6  three   2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am not sure I understand correctly your question (your example does not fit the question in any way), I can only suggest the hint:

Set <- rbind(Set1, Set2)

rv <- Set[Set[, "Object"] %in% duplicated(Set[, "Object"]), ]